# How to push an item into a Vec and continue using it?

Tags: rust

I am trying to add an item to a `Vec<T>`, call a function and await it. I am still wrapping my head around the ownership and borrow rules. I understand the below won't work:

```
pub async fn begin_session(&mut self, stream: TcpStream) {
    let session = Session::new(stream);
    self.sessions.push(session);
            
    session.start_receiver().await; // obviously, won't work
}
```

The solution that I came up with below doesn't seem ideal (or thread-safe) to me:

```
pub async fn begin_session(&mut self, stream: TcpStream) {
    let session = Session::new(stream);
    self.sessions.push(session);

    let session = self.sessions.last().unwrap();
    
    session.start_receiver().await; // That works.
}
```

Is there a function in `Vec<T>` that does a `push(T)` and also returns `T`?

Comment: If session is cloneable you may do the following `self.sessions.push(session.clone());`

Comment: Safe Rust is thread-safe.  In this case, no other thread can simultaneously hold a mutable reference to `self` so you can be sure that `self.sessions` is unchanged between `push` and `last`.

Comment: @eggyal Free of data races, not thread-safe.

Comment: @Acorn: agreed, loose language on my part; I think a data race was the concern here however?

Comment: @eggyal I'd think so, yeah. Sorry for being pedantic. I prefer that wording to avoid beginners thinking there are no other kinds of race conditions, deadlocks, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> just doesn't seem ideal (or thread-safe) to me

It might not be ideal if the optimizer does not realize that the `unwrap()` will always be successful.

However, thread-safety does not play a role here: if you are planning to share the `Vec` or your `Self` later on, you will have to take care of that somehow.

> Is there a function in `Vec` that does a `push(T)` and then also return `T`?

If it were there, then such a method would most likely return a `&T` or a `&mut T` which you can then copy or clone if needed. Other people may prefer to return the index instead. There are many possibilities depending on what you exactly need.

Whatever is best for your project, remember that you can add the method yourself to `Vec`. For instance:

```
trait PushReturn<T> {
    fn push_return(&mut self, t: T) -> &mut T;
}

impl<T> PushReturn<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn push_return(&mut self, t: T) -> &mut T {
        self.push(t);
        self.last_mut().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good case in which to use reference-counted objects in the form of [`std::rc::Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html).

Your code might end up looking something like this:

```rust
pub async fn begin_session(&mut self, stream: TcpStream) {
    let session = Rc::new(Session::new(stream));
    self.sessions.push(Rc::clone(&session));

    &session.start_receiver().await;
}
```

When you clone an `Rc`, you're just cloning the reference to the object, and increasing the reference count. You're not cloning the object itself.

Disclaimer: I, too, am just learning Rust. It would be good to get a second opinion on this.

Comment: This adds a bit of runtime overhead that may not be necessary in the OP’s case.